# How do I terminate a window in tmux?

Tags: window, tmux

How do I terminate a window in tmux? Like the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> shortcut in [screen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen), where <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> is the prefix.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Kent's response fully answered your question, however if you are looking to change tmux's configuration to be similar to GNU Screen, here's a tmux.conf that I've used to accomplish this:

```
# Prefix key
set -g prefix C-a
unbind C-b
bind C-a send-prefix

# Keys
bind k confirm kill-window
bind K confirm kill-server
bind % split-window -h
bind : split-window -v
bind < resize-pane -L 1
bind > resize-pane -R 1
bind - resize-pane -D 1
bind + resize-pane -U 1
bind . command-prompt
bind a last-window
bind space command-prompt -p index "select-window"
bind r source-file ~/.tmux.conf

# Options
set -g bell-action none
set -g set-titles on
set -g set-titles-string "tmux (#I:#W)"
set -g base-index 1
set -g status-left ""
set -g status-left-attr bold
set -g status-right "tmux"
set -g pane-active-border-bg black
set -g pane-active-border-fg black
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"

# Window options
setw -g monitor-activity off
setw -g automatic-rename off

# Colors
setw -g window-status-current-fg colour191
set -g status-bg default
set -g status-fg white
set -g message-bg default
set -g message-fg colour191
```

Comment: This is overly verbose and doesn't indicate where the question is answered

Answer (score 423):

try   `Prefix` + <kbd>&</kbd>

if you have

```
bind q killp
```

in your `.tmux.conf`, you can press `Prefix` + <kbd>q</kbd> to kill the window too, only if there is only one panel in that window.

if you have multiple panes and want to kill the whole window at once use `killw` instead of `killp` in your config.

**the default of Prefix above is** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>,
**so to terminate window by default you can use** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> <kbd>&</kbd>

Comment: This works fine: `Ctrl+b &`, note, that you have to confirm with `y` to really kill the current window incluning all panes in that window. You will get be placed inside the window that you used last before that.

Comment: It's worth noting that by default `Prefix` + `q` shows pane number, so assigning `killp` to this combination will override this shortcut.

Comment: `Ctrl+b &` terminates the session as well

Answer (score 198):

`<Prefix>` `&` for killing a window

`<Prefix>` `x` for killing a pane

If there is only one pane (i.e. the window is not split into multiple panes, `<Prefix>` `x` would kill the window)

As always iterated, `<Prefix>` is generally `CTRL+b`. (I think for beginner questions, we can just say `CTRL+b` all the time, and not talk about prefix at all, but anyway :) )

Comment: I couldn't kill just the pane with <prefix> x, only with <prefix> :, then typing [`respawn-pane -k`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/88393/209677).

Answer (score 125):

Generally:

```
tmux kill-window -t window-number
```

So for example, if you are in window 1 and you want to kill window 9:

```
tmux kill-window -t 9
```

Comment: This. (Thank you so much by the way!) If done remotely where tmux is running in some other terminal, one can do `INFO=$(tmux new-window -P notepad)` followed by `tmux kill-window -t $INFO`.

Comment: To kill a specific pane `tmux kill-pane -t 1`, where 1 is the pane number

Answer (score 114):

For me solution looks like:

1. `ctrl+b q` to show pane numbers.
2. `ctrl+b x` to kill pane.

Killing last pane will kill window.

Comment: This is the best solution when you've just finished a process inside a tmux window.

Comment: `Killing last pane will kill window`. Does not work for me? I'm using mac

Comment: yes, I think this is the best solution ever, ever and ever.

Comment: `ctrl+b x` will always ask me whether I want to kill pane 0 even if I'm on pane 5. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @CorneliusRoemer If your prefix is `ctrl+b` then to kill specific window (if you are on window 5). `prefix + &` will kill the windows 5 instead of windows 0.

Answer (score 33):

If you just want to do it once, without adding a shortcut, you can always type

```
<prefix> 
:
kill-window
<enter>
```

Answer (score 21):

`ctrl + d` kills a window in linux terminal, also works in tmux.

This is kind of a approach.

Comment: Note that this shortcut just means "end of data". It only works if the currently running process in the tmux pane accepts this signal and terminates itself upon receiving it (e.g. as bash does). Because there is no process around in the pane, it gets closed by tmux. Does not work in all cases.

Comment: this is wat I was looking for.

Comment: This is OK if there is a running shell in the window, but if there is just a frozen application, something more brutal is needed. Nikolay Fominyh's answer works fine.

Comment: This only kills a pane, not a window.

Comment: This doesn't do anything with `remain-on-exit` windows.

Comment: This detached from my entire session and put me back into bash. Was able to reconnect to the session though.

Answer (score 12):

Lot's of different ways to do this, but my favorite is simply typing 'exit' on the bash prompt.

Comment: This presumes bash is running in the window.  The window I wanted to kill which led me to this page is the list of tmux commands - that has no shell to exit.

Comment: If you were looking at the list of commands displayed by <prefix>+?, you can leave that by pressing q or <RET>.

Answer (score 11):

While you asked *how to kill a window resp. pane*, I often wouldn't want to kill it but simply to get it back to a working state (the layout of panes is of importance to me, killing a pane destroys it so I must recreate it); tmux provides the `respawn` commands to that effect: `respawn-pane` resp. `respawn-window`. Just that people like me may find this solution here.

Answer (score 10):

By default
`<Prefix>` & for killing a window
`<Prefix>` x for killing a pane
And you can add config info

```
vi ~/.tmux.conf
bind-key X kill-session
```

then
`<Prefix>` X for killing a session

Comment: This might come in handy for beginners. `<Prefix>` by default is `Ctrl+b` which means, one first needs to press `Ctrl` and `b` buttons together and then press the mentioned key. for example for deleting a pane, you first go into command mode by Ctrl+b (i.e pressing prefix) and then pressing x on your keyboard.

Answer (score -5):

I can confirm following working on tmux running in ssh via Windows Command:

**Copy**: Press `shift`, select using mouse, press `Ctrl+Shift+C`

**Paste**: `Shift+Right click`

No special settings were needed.