# ctrl-d does not close pane in tmux when vim editor is open

Tags: tmux

I have recently started using tmux, I noticed that the ctrl-d command does not close the pane in tmux when a vim editor has been opened in that pane. What additional config needs to be done to get this working? I am using tmux 1.8.

Comment: Ctrl-d isn't a tmux command. It signals "end of input" in many programs though, including the shell, which will then exit.

Comment: how to close window/pane in tmux: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771557/how-to-terminate-a-window-in-tmux/7773305#7773305

Comment: <Prefix> & for killing a window, <Prefix> x for killing a pane. This usually asks for confirmation, if you do not want the confirmation then include the following in your .tmux.conf "bind-key & kill-window" and "bind-key x kill-pane"